# Symfony controller: Which database driver is currently being used?

Tags: php, symfony

In a Symfony controller’s action, how can I find out which database driver is currently being used? Something like

```php
public function testAction(Request $request)
{
    // How to accomplish this?
    switch ($this->getDoctrine()->getDriverName()) {
        case 'pdo_mysql':
            // execute MySQL-specific query…
            break;
        case 'pdo_sqlite':
            // execute SQLite-specific query…
            break;
        default:
            // …
    }

    return $this->render(/* … */);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `$this->getDoctrine()->getConnection( )->getDriver()` 
The getConnection() will return object. You can access all their details in that object

Ref [this](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/dbal/2.1/class-Doctrine.DBAL.Connection.html)

Comment: Thanks! To be precise, it’s `$this->getDoctrine()->getConnection()->getDriver()->getName()` what I’ve been asking for. Also, what do you mean with “will the connection Object”?

Comment: Nothing getConnection() will return object. You can access all their details in that object